# Code for sizeof?

Tags: c, sizeof

I was trying to write a simple code which acts as sizeof (specifically for int in this code). But why is it showing 1 as output? It should be 4.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int SIZEOF(int *);

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Size is:%d bytes\n",SIZEOF(&a));

    return 0;
}

int SIZEOF(int *p1)
{
    int *p2;
    p2=p1;

    p1++;

    return (p1-p2);
}
```

Comment: For the same reason `p1++` increments by `sizeof(int)`, `p1-p2` is the difference in units of `sizeof(int)`. Cast to `char*` first, which always has a size of 1.

Comment: `+ 1` to pointer makes it pointing to next location of its own type. (this is not increment to address value but logical increment that is very helpful in programming) Pointer arithmetic are different then value  arithmetic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic works in units of the size of the pointed-to type.  When you do `p1 - p2`, you get the number of `int` units, not the number of `char` units.  Add some casts:

```
return (char *)p1 - (char *)p2;
```

Editorial note: `SIZEOF` should probably return `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic hits again. Just like `p1++` increments the pointer by `1 * sizeof(pointer)`, `p1-p2` divides the result by `sizeof(p1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the thing being pointed to into account. If you have a pointer `p` to an array of any data type, `++p` will advance the pointer by the size of the data. When you subtract the two, the result is divided by the size.

There is no portable way to implement this without using the sizeof keyword.